# How do I override the content region for a specific page?

Tags: theming

I want to override the content region for a specific page, but using the hook `page--mypage--region--content.tpl.php` won't work. How should I name it?

My site supports block override, I tested this with a dummy `region.tpl.php` and I currently use a custom `page.tpl.php`.

Comment: Why do you want to override the content region for a specific page? Isn't that the same as just having some specific content on a specific page?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have done this before on one or two sites where I didn't want to Panel out the entire site, but needed some extra wrappers / inner divs on particular pages to get what the creative director wanted.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear more about the requirements from OP, for example additional wrappers could be added in a node template or view template etc.. some more info would help clarify the solution.

Comment: I want to embed a site-wide contact form in a custom node, with other elements in it, and I didn't want to rewrite the whole page template for the section; I figured the best I could do was override the content region. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like you could just make a webform node page, using the webform module.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to override preprocess region

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
    if(CONDITION){
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'regionspecial__' . $variables['region'];
    }
    print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']); // comment this statement
}
```

After that your template suggestion name will be 'regionspecial--content.tpl.php' For certain desired condition.  Once you clear Drupal's caches your new template file should start being used for that region. It might be worth noting that you'll probably need a copy of the core region.tpl.php file somewhere in your theme folder as well, or the theme registry might not pick up your custom file.

Comment: What would be a good `CONDITION` to use?

Comment: May be arg(0) is 'test' or whatever